# setuptools and files not installed

Tags: python

So the issue is quite confusing.
Conventionally I have a basic structure in a python package

```
setup.py
requirements.txt
src/
  package_name/
     file1.py
     file2.py
    __init__.py
```

The above installs great but the one below doesnt.

```
setup.py
requirements.txt
src/
   file1.py
   file2.py
   __init__.py
```

things that dont work

```
find_packages()
find_packages(where="src")
find_packages(where="./src")
```

when getting into python i can import src but thats not how packages are supposed to work

```
from src import file1
```

Also, I wish I could change the folder structure but constrained by requirements.

Thanks in advance and happy coding.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ?

Comment: when I use the first structure i can run from package_name.file1 import Class but I cant do that with the 2nd folder structure

Comment: Well, that's because `package_name` does not exist anymore. You removed it, so of course you cannot use it.

Comment: Is there any solution that states all items in src -> put in module named package_name